# Remove or hide column from a field within a one2many XML Odoo field

Tags: xml, odoo, qweb

I have a one2many field(product_pricelist_item_ids) of type `product.pricelist.item` using in form view of `product.template`

I have tried with:

```
invisible = "context.get ('product_variants_without', False)"
```

passing the context in the parent field:

```
<field name = "product_pricelist_item_ids" widget = "one2many" context = "{'product_variants_without': product_variants_without}">
```

but it does not hide you!

I have tried with:

```
attrs = "{'required': [('applied_on', '=', '0_product_variant')], 'invisible': [('product_variants_without', '=', True)]}"
```

with:

```
attrs = "{'required': [('applied_on', '=', '0_product_variant')], 'invisible': [('product_variants_without', '=', [])]}"
```

I also read that you can only hide the column using `invisible="context.get...`, but the context does not work for me since I do not get any information, any recommendation or guide?
Code xml:

```
<field name="product_pricelist_item_ids" widget="one2many"  context="{'product_variants_without': product_variants_without}">
    <tree string="Descuentos" editable="bottom" multi_edit="1" >
        <field name="product_id"
          groups="product.group_product_variant"
          invisible="context.get('product_variants_without', False)" //I don't have the context
          readonly="context.get('active_model')=='product.product'"
          attrs="{'required': [('applied_on', '=', '0_product_variant')], 'invisible': [('product_variants_without', '=', True)]}" //not work
          domain="['|', '|',
            ('id', '=', context.get('default_product_id', 0)),
            ('product_tmpl_id', '=', parent.id),
            ('categ_id', '=', context.get('default_categ_id', 0)), '|', ('company_id', '=', company_id), ('company_id', '=', False)
          ]"
          options="{'no_create_edit':1, 'no_open': 1, 'no_create': True}"
          />

    </tree>
</field>
```

Comment: if you want to make a field in a o2m invisible. use the attr `column_invisible` in place for `invisible`

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the `context` from Actions(from anylevel) then you get the context on that field it will be perform based on value,

Example - Action - **Sales Teams**

```
<record id="sales_team.crm_team_salesteams_act" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="context">{'in_sales_app': True}</field><!-- Context is Pass here from Action-->
</record>
```

From here it passes the context so you can try the same like the `context` **product_variants_without**  from Product Actions and inside the form view you have `o2m fields` so get the context and make hide/show.

```
<field name="product_pricelist_item_ids" invisible="context.get('product_variants_without', True)"/>
```

Comment: I am inheriting the form view from `ref = "product.product_template_form_view" ` and with that I do a `<xpath expr="." position="replace">` to create my own product.template form as I would do in that case?

Comment: no, XPath you take to keep as it is, but the ref I'm saying that you have to pass context from some level, so pass from the menu when product is clicked the product action pass the context and you have already done the XPath to the field so add the invisible based on context value.